# How to avoid duplicating same properties in different classes in my case?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I want to have a class that has all the properties of `VehicleConfig` and `ExtendedTransportConfig`. Since I cannot inherit from multiple classes, I decided to solve this by creating `ExtendedVehicleConfig` and duplicated all properties of `VehicleConfig` into `ExtendedVehicleConfig`. Now `Car3Config` can inherit from `ExtendedVehicleConfig`. This is not an ideal solution since every time I add/remove properites from `VehicleConfig` I'll have to add/remove from `ExtendedVehicleConfig` too. I could use interface, but that will require to change other classes to interfaces and still requirs me to define same properties in both classes. Is there a better solution?

```
public class TransportConfig
{
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class VehicleConfig : TransportConfig
{
   public int Prop2 { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Car1Config : VehicleConfig 
{
   public int Prop3 { get; set; }
   ...
}


public class ExtendedTransportConfig : TransportConfig
{
   public int Prop4 { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Car2Config : ExtendedTransportConfig  
{
   public int Prop5 { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

**Solution**

```
public class Car3Config : ExtendedVehicleConfig  
{
   public int Prop6 { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class ExtendedVehicleConfig : ExtendedTransportConfig
{
   public int Prop2 { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even multiple inheritance would not solve the problem, because a DerivedCarConfig should derive from a BaseCarConfig which is in turn inheriting from VehicleConfig and TransportConfig. But then this DerivedCarConfig cannot re-inherit from more derived Vehicle- and Transport-configs. What would the use case for such a construction be?

I would declare independant class hierarchies for vehicle and transport configurations:

```cs
public class VehicleConfig
{
    public int VehicleProp1 { get; }

}
public class VehicleConfig2 : VehicleConfig
{
    public int VehicleProp2 { get; }
}
public class VehicleConfig3 : VehicleConfig2
{
    public int VehicleProp3 { get; }
}

public class TransportConfig
{
    public int TransportProp1 { get; }
}
public class TransportConfig2 : TransportConfig
{
    public int TransportProp2 { get; }
}
public class TransportConfig3 : TransportConfig2
{
    public int TransportProp3 { get; }
}
```

Then you can declare a car configuration hierarchy like this

```cs
public class CarConfig
{
    public CarConfig()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected virtual void Initialize()
    {
        VehicleConfig = new VehicleConfig();
        TransportConfig = new TransportConfig();
    }

    public VehicleConfig VehicleConfig { get; protected set; }
    public TransportConfig TransportConfig { get; protected set; }
}

public class CarConfig2 : CarConfig
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        VehicleConfig = new VehicleConfig2();
        TransportConfig = new TransportConfig2();
    }
}

public class CarConfig3 : CarConfig2
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        VehicleConfig = new VehicleConfig3();
        TransportConfig = new TransportConfig3();
    }
}
```

Note that by using polymorphism, you will not even need to write code like:

```cs
if (car.VehicleConfig is VehicleConfig2 vc2) { 
    Print(vc2.VehicleProp2); 
}
```

The point is to integrate the methods into the configuration classes themselves. E.g.:

```cs
public class VehicleConfig
{
    public int VehicleProp1 { get; }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VehicleProp1);
    }
}

public class VehicleConfig2 : VehicleConfig
{
    public int VehicleProp2 { get; }

    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine(VehicleProp2);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call:

```cs
car.VehicleConfig.Print();
```

And this will print the right things, no matter whether `car` is a `CarConfig` or a `CarConfig5`.

Note that print is just an example. You would integrate all the things you do with configurations into the configurations, like save and restore configuration, display, validation etc., etc.

---

Or you could create a dynamic car configuration where you can freely mix vehicle- and transport-configurations of different inheritance levels:

```cs
public class DynamicCarConfig
{
    public DynamicCarConfig(VehicleConfig vehicleConfig, TransportConfig transportConfig)
    {
        VehicleConfig = vehicleConfig;
        TransportConfig = transportConfig;
    }

    public VehicleConfig VehicleConfig { get; }
    public TransportConfig TransportConfig { get; }
}
```

```cs
var car = new DynamicCarConfig(
    new VehicleConfig3(),
    new TransportConfig2());
```

---

Other approaches could use dictionaries to store properties by name.